# java hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have the following table structure in my database:

```
 Table A:                     Table B:                       Table C:
 _______________________      ______________________________  ______________________
 | Field | Type | Key  |     | Field | Type | Key          |  | Field | Type | Key  |   
 ______________________|     |_____________________________|  |_____________________|
 | a_id  | Int  | PRI  |     | a_id  | Int  | FK of A(a_id)|  | c_id  | Int  | PRI  |
 |     ...       ...   |     | c_id  | Int  | FK of C(c_id)|  |       ...           |
 |_____________________|      ______________________________  |_____________________|
```

And the object:

```
  class A {
        List<C> list;
        ...
   }
```

Now I would like to receive an object A from the database with all C objects that are combined by the table B. I have the Criteria to receive the correct Object A but I don't know how to receive a List of the corresponding C Objects:

```
    Criteria crit = ...;
    A a = crit.uniqueResult();
```

Here is the SQL query that gives me the correct result and which should now be 'translated' in a Criteria:

```
 select c.* 
 from A as a, 
      B as b, 
      C as c 
 where a.a_id = b.a_id and b.c_id = c.c_id;
```

Does anyone know how to formulate the Criteria?

Comment: Have you tried using HQL instead of the Criteria api? How does your entities look like?

Comment: All other database accesses are done with Criterias therefore I'd like to stick to that one; I added the SQL query that works and that one should be 'translated' in a Criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
class A {
    List<C> list;
    ...
}
```

and both `A` and `C` are `@Entity`s, your criteria would have to look like this:

```
// Create criteria on class A
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);
```

In this moment if you do a `criteria.list()` you will get all `A` objects, each with a list of `C` values for which you have only the ids. In order to bring the full C objects you need an extra :

```
criteria.createAlias("list", "listC");
```

This will create an alias for (i.e. inner join) `A` with `C`. Now, supposing you have an **a** (of class `A`) you can do `a.getList().get(i).getWhateverFieldFromC()`; so now you have for every instance of `A` its list of `C`s populated.

Don't forget at the end to do a `criteria.list()` to retrieve the list. That would be all.

**P.S. This is assuming (of course) that entities `A` and `C` are correctly mapped.**